# mysql weird behavior acting like false=string is true

Tags: mysql

I was testing some queries and I got a weird result.

I tested the following query

```
SELECT * FROM Persons where username = 'admin' and password = username = 'a'
```

this returns the admin's credits(username and password)

So if I'm correct, `password = username = 'a'` is being returned true..

but how?

so I tested more queries and got the following result

```
Select 1 from Persons where 1=1='a';//returns nothing
select 1 from Persons where 1=2='a';//returns 1
```

so true='a' is false and false='a' is true?

Thank you,

Comment: **WARNING**: You should *never* store passwords as plain-text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably this:

```
password = username
```

returns `false` which for MySql is evaluated as `0`.
Then this:

```
0 = 'a'
```

after MySql implicitly tries to convert `'a'` to a number to evaluate the expression and because `'a'` can't be converted to a number the result of the conversion is `0`.
You can find everything you need to know about implicit conversions here: 12.3 [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html).
So:

```
0 = 0
```

returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql casts variables to the left variable type.
So expression `password = username = 'a'` may be expressed like this:

`password = username` // 0 (false)

`0 = 'a'` // 1 (true), because CAST('a' AS INTEGER) = 0

Same thing to `1=1='a'`:
`1=1` // 1 (true)
`1='a'` // 0 (false), because CAST('a' AS INTEGER) = 0

And for `1=2='a'`:

`1=2` // 0 (false)

`0='a'` // 1 (true), because CAST('a' AS INTEGER) = 0

You can try next query to check this things:

```
SELECT "string1" = "string2", 0 = "a", CAST('a' AS INTEGER);
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, when you do `x=y=z` what really happens is `(x=y)=z` meaning that you are comparing `password = username` (false, for every use who knows how to choose a strong password...) to 'a'.

Now, the thing about booleans in mySql is that they are represented as tinyint - 1 is true, 0 is false. you can see that by running `select true` - you'll get 1 as result.
This also works with strings - '1' when compared with boolean is true, any other string is false, you can run this two and see you'll get 1 as result:

```
select true = 1;
select true = '1';
select false = 0;
select false = '0';
select false = 'any other string';
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL treats false as 0 and true as 1.  That allows MySQL-specific hacks like

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(active = 1) active, SUM(active <> 1)inactive FROM tbl
```

to do some mild pivot-style reporting.

It looks like MySQL's processing of WHERE clauses containing more than one comparer runs left to right.   So

```
  SELECT 1 = 1
```

gives 1, and so does both of these two equivalent expressions.

```
  SELECT 1 = 1 = 1, (1 = 1) = 1
```

Now,  `0 = 'a'` returns 1 (true) because of another MySQL quirk that coerces strings to integers by interpreting the leading digits of the string as an integer.  So `7 = '7a'` is 1 (true) as is `0 = '0a'` (and `0 = 'a'`). But `6 = '7a'` is false (0).

The moral of the story? For clear code avoid WHERE clauses with more than one comparer.